# Is there any option to tell to helm to not wait till post install hook is completed?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, post-install

We are using helm to deploy k8s project/set of pods.
Till now "helm install" comes out immediately after loading scripts.
We have added "post install" hook and the "helm install" waits for some time and comes out with error "timed out waiting for the condition".

Is there any option to make "helm install" don't wait till post install is completed ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not implemented for helm3 [hooks defined as Job or Pod](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/#hooks-and-the-release-lifecycle). There are several workarounds mentioned in the [open ticket](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5891).

Alternatively, run `helm install --wait --timeout 15m` to prevent the timeout error.